# codeigniter email displays HTML tags in email

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have a email sending code in codeigniter. I am able to send email but the HTML displays tags in the email. I have used mailtype as HTML. But it still does not work. This is my email function.

```
public function email_send($to_email,$subject,$message,$attach) 
    {
        $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host']    = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $config['smtp_user']    = 'dsouzaj184@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass']    = 'abcd#1234';
        $config['charset']    = 'UTF-8';
        $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl'; 
        $config['priority'] = 1;     
        //$config['newline']    = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
        $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not 
        $config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
        $config['newline'] = '\r\n';        



        $this->load->library('email',$config);  
        $this->email->clear(true);
        //$this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->email->set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        //$this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
        $this->email->from('dsouzaj184@gmail.com', 'Global Admin');
        $this->email->to($to_email);        
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);  

        // return $to_email; 

        if($attach != '') { 
            $this->email->attach($attach);  
        }

       if($this->email->send()) { 
            $this->email->clear(true);
            return 1;

        } else {  
            //print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add wordwrap in config array as true

```
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```

and if it wont solve your problem than change

```
        $this->load->library('email',$config);  
        $this->email->clear(true);
        //$this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->email->set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        //$this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
```

to

```
    $this->load->library('email');  
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
    $this->email->clear();
```